# Google Calendar Charts for Swift / iOS

Tags: ios, swift, charts, calendar, core-plot

I'm looking for a plugin / tips on how to build calendar chart in an iOS app. The chart should look like the Google calendar chart. So far I haven't found any documentation on this.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/calendar

Thank you!